# Cancel Button in SearchBar Causing app to crash (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

When I run the app the rest of the search bar is working properly, however, when I press the cancel button on the search bar it crashes the program with the error

```
{System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    at App.SearchPage+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<SearchBar_TextChanged>b__0 (System.String Name) [0x00000] in /Users}
```

This problem is only happening on the IOS app since the Android app does not include the cancel button.

Comment: please show the relevant code.  Does the stack trace show the origin of the exception?

Comment: May when you are watching TextChanged event it is firing the event with null text, add null check in your code.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. The problem was that when i pressed the cancel it was giving a null which i did not have a check for. Thanks Akash

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)